# error :- {"code":"403", "message":"HMAC validation Failure"}

Tags: java, payment-gateway

Here i am attaching code and a link consist of full code , have a look on it:-
My authorization header seams to be coming of same length as mentioned in official site of payeezy.I have also make my hmacString of same order as mentioned in this link (https://developer.payeezy.com/content/hmac-validation-failure) . After doing all this i am still getting this same issue

```
public static String excutePost(String urlParameters) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/transactions");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            // Create connection
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", headerContentType);
            connection.setRequestProperty("apikey ", apikey);
            connection.setRequestProperty("token", MerchantToken);
            connection
                    .setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
            connection.setRequestProperty("timestamp", ""+epoch);
            connection.setRequestProperty("nonce", ""+nonce);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

            // Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is full java class code :- http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.WwZ9v6FX1a6/latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solve this error by sending direct String as parameter in api url hit.Here i am posting some of my code which solve my error :-

```html
String str = "{\"amount\":\"1299\",\"merchant_ref\":\"Astonishing-Sale\",\"transaction_type\":\"authorize\",\"credit_card\":{\"card_number\":\"4788250000028291\",\"cvv\":\"123\",\"exp_date\": \"1020\",\"cardholder_name\": \"John Smith\",\"type\": \"visa\"},\"method\": \"credit_card\",\"currency_code\": \"USD\"}";
```

now this String will be used in generating my authorisation key.
**the whole process is defined below** :-

```html
getSecurityKeys(apikey, pzsecret,str);

private static Map<String, String> getSecurityKeys(String appId,
   String secureId, String payLoad) throws Exception {
  Map<String, String> returnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  try {
   returnMap.put(NONCE, Long.toString(nonce));
   returnMap.put(APIKEY, appId);
   returnMap.put(TIMESTAMP, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
   returnMap.put(TOKEN, MerchantToken);
   returnMap.put(APISECRET, pzsecret);
   returnMap.put(PAYLOAD, payLoad);
   returnMap.put(AUTHORIZE, getMacValue(returnMap));
   authorizationHeader = returnMap.get(AUTHORIZE);
   return returnMap;

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
 }

 public static String getMacValue(Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
  String apiSecret = data.get(APISECRET);
  SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(apiSecret.getBytes(),
    "HmacSHA256");
  mac.init(secret_key);
  StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
  buff.append(data.get(APIKEY)).append(data.get(NONCE))
    .append(data.get(TIMESTAMP));
  if (data.get(TOKEN) != null)
   buff.append(data.get(TOKEN));
  if (data.get(PAYLOAD) != null)
   buff.append(data.get(PAYLOAD));
  byte[] macHash = mac.doFinal(buff.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
  String authorizeString = Base64.encodeBase64String(toHex(macHash));
  return authorizeString;
 }
```

Now finally you can pass direct String(i.e str) as parameter in hitting post api in java.

hope it helps other to integrate payeezy payment gateway without using any dependencies.
Happy Codeing!!!

Answer (score 1):

You must generate a new `timestamp` and `nonce` for **every** request, i.e., every new request must have its unique `timestamp` and `nonce`.

In java, `timestamp` can be set as `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `nonce` can be set using `UUID` (`UUID.randomUUID().toString()`).

Finally, make sure that your `Authorization` is correctly computed (I see they use `HMAC-SHA1` using API secret key).

I hope this helps.

---

**Edit**: As suspected, it's your `HMAC-SHA1` Authorization value that is incorrect. I get the following response when running your code (after few coding of my own).

```
Connection = keep-alive
Content-Length = 51
Content-Type = application/json
{"code":"403", "message":"HMAC validation Failure"}
```

Make sure that you compute your `HMAC-SHA1` value correctly (as I said above).

See the below (updated) code that you can compile and run for yourself. You will need Java 8 as it comes with Base 64 encoder/decoder now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

//import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class MainJava {
    private static final String    myEncoding            = "UTF-8";
    private static final String    myMessageDigest        = "SHA-1";
    private static final String    myKeySpec            = "HmacSHA1";
    private static String        NEWLINE                = "\n";
    private static String        authorizationHeader;
    private static String        contentSha1;
    // private static String keyId = "230297";
    // private static String hmacKey = "tcwR9r1OR85V9bcV5tc7a9d1XkWigjqY";
    private static String        ApiSecretkey        = "0779eb593286b278aaf8cfcf83c8e33bc757d53a8a642b53d24d63bda844da5b";
    private static String        MerchantToken        = "fdoa-a480ce8951daa73262734cf102641994c1e55e7cdf4c02b6";
    private static String        reportingToken        = "e56a0223d0415067";
    private static String        apikey                = "XSjbv8PLDINJ28qXLEYAhcrz8rxKXQ4Y";
    private static long            nonce;
    public static String        headerContentType    = "application/json";
    private static long            epoch;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json_string_dataTwo = "{\"type\":\"visa\",\"cardholder_name\":\"John Smith\",\"card_number\":\"4788250000028291\",\"exp_date\":1020,\"cvv\":\"123\"}";
        // String json_string =
        // "{\"gateway_id\":\"AI2010-01\",\"password\":\"w226638qtot48xu503zumwt2iy46g26q\",\"transaction_type\":\"00\",\"amount\":10,\"cardholder_name\":\"test\",\"cc_number\":\"4111111111111111\",\"cc_expiry\":\"1219\"}";
        String json_string_data = "{\"merchant_ref\":\"Astonishing-Sale\",\"transaction_type\":\"authorize\",\"method\":\"credit_card\",\"amount\":1299,\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"credit_card\":"
                + json_string_dataTwo + "}";
        // "{\r\n  \"merchant_ref\": \"Astonishing-Sale\",\r\n  \"transaction_type\": \"authorize\",\r\n  \"method\": \"credit_card\",\r\n  \"amount\": \"1299\",\r\n  \"currency_code\": \"USD\",\r\n  \"credit_card\": {\r\n    \"type\": \"visa\",\r\n    \"cardholder_name\": \"John Smith\",\r\n    \"card_number\": \"4788250000028291\",\r\n    \"exp_date\": \"1020\",\r\n    \"cvv\": \"123\"\r\n  }\r\n}";

        epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();// / 1000;
        // nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        nonce = Math.abs(SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextLong());
        contentSha1 = contentSha1(json_string_data);
        authorizationHeader = authHeader(epoch, contentSha1);
        System.out.println(excutePost(json_string_data));
    }

    private static String authHeader(long hashTime, String contentSha1) {
        String authorizationHeader = null;
        try {
            String hmacString = "POST" + NEWLINE + "application/json" + NEWLINE + contentSha1 + NEWLINE + hashTime + NEWLINE + apikey + NEWLINE
                    + new URI("https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/transactions");

            return sha1(hmacString, ApiSecretkey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static String contentSha1(String content) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
        md.update(content.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, content.length());
        sha1hash = md.digest();
        return convertToHex(sha1hash);
    }

    private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int halfbyte = data[i] >>> 4 & 0xF;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do {
                if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
                    buf.append((char) (48 + halfbyte));
                else
                    buf.append((char) (97 + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = data[i] & 0xF;
            } while (two_halfs++ < 1);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

//     private static String sha1(String s, String keyString) {
//     Base64 base64 = new Base64();
//     try {
//     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8"),
//     "HmacSHA1");
//     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
//     mac.init(key);
//     byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//    
//     return new String(base64.encode(bytes));
//     } catch (Exception e) {
//     throw new RuntimeException(e);
//     }
//     }
    private static String sha1(String s, String keyString) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
            sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
            bytes = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //return new String(Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    }

    private static String hashTime() {
        String time = getUTCFormattedDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        return time;
    }

    private static String getUTCFormattedDate(String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return dateFormat.format(new Date());
    }

    public static String excutePost(String urlParameters) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(urlParameters);
    System.out.println(headerContentType);
    System.out.println(MerchantToken);
    System.out.println(authorizationHeader);
    System.out.println(epoch);
    System.out.println(nonce);
        URL url = new URL("https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/transactions");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            // Create connection
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", headerContentType);
            connection.setRequestProperty("apikey ", apikey);
            connection.setRequestProperty("token", MerchantToken);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
            connection.setRequestProperty("timestamp", "" + epoch);
            connection.setRequestProperty("nonce", "" + nonce);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

            // Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = null;
            int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        try {
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (statusCode >= 400) {
                is = connection.getErrorStream();
            }
        }
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, yes i know this that i have to generate my time-stamp and nonce every time when i hit the api correspondingly my authentication header also get generated uniquely .. here i am sending you my main java class ...please have a look on it and tell me that where i am doing wrong ... (http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.WwZ9v6FX1a6/latest)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your effort , i will try it and let you know that how it goes :)

Comment: Hey , Sindi ..I just run your code on my machine and yes i am getting this same issue which you mentioned above...i have not updated my java version of eclipse  but have used java.util,base64 class from this site(http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Base64.java#Base64) can you please tell me that which method i should use to generate my Hmac key. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you run your edited code and test it? What result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

My only issue is with the character encoding, where I assume UTF-8. I suspect that the error lies elsewhere.

```
        // Send request
        byte[] data = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedOutputStream wr = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(data);
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

And `\r`, CR, does not serve as line separator (apart from old MacOS).

```
           response.append("\r\n"); // Or '\n'
```

Comment: Hey, Eggen thanks for your reply ...but still i am getting same error :-
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value: AMru2osZZnotc25nRr7/dAOwkV/S3J1T7Yn7zs2XpFc=

Comment: Also , when i try to debug the code i found something like :- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Comment: **Try leave out the trailing `=` padding characters.**

Comment: Sorry  i didn’t get your point ... can you please elaborate it ,Thanks

Comment: That Base64 key has at the end of its value redundant equals signs. You could try without. What else? `URLEncoder.encode(value)` might still be another, even more dubious, attempt.